# Laravel Mix runs in production mode but not in development mode

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

If I run Laravel Mix as

```
npm run production
```

everything works, but if I run

```
npm run development
```

I got

```
26% building 136/199 modules 63 active ...odules\vue-loader\lib\index.js??vue-loader-options!L:\laravel\resources\js\components [...]
```

There is no error but it do nothing for over a hour. It stops all the time at the same component. But again it works if I use the first command.

Is there a cache or something I could empty?

Answer (score 0):

I confused the syntax of the slots from outside and inside the slots - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

After I fixed that, the process went through.